# Iterating 2 lists different lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x

im iterating list1 in reverse to find the first element that is lower than the highest possible number in list2 but im running into problems when list1 is significantly shorter than list2 even though list2 has a value < i.

```
    lst1 = [2, 4]
    lst2 = [3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13]

    val = None
    for i in lst1[::-1]:
        if i < lst2[-1]:
            val = i
    index = val
```

Comment: Can you add a toy example with expected output?

Comment: The questions seems not very clear. Please put an example as @yatu suggested

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem here. You code does run and the output is 2, which is indeed the number that is lower than the highest (in lst1) and also lower than the highest number in lst2

Comment: yes, i agree, there's something else causing the error. I'll continue to investigate it. thanks.

Comment: unrelated: import bisect for more efficient functions that do most of what you want (assuming the lists are already sorted). also indentation.